# How do I properly use local storage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, modernizr

EDIT: Since my question seems to be unclear I will rephrase my question.

I need to:

- Store variables on local storage. I have a button that does this.
- Retrieve the values of the variables but only if there are any value in the local storage. If not, then I want to set the standard value.
- Delete local storage. I also have a button for that.

I'm using the following code in this situation but variable `scrapMetal` is always returned as true.

Javascript:

```
//Been to variables
var beenToPrison = true;

//Item variables
var scrapMetal = false;

//Room variables
var currentRoom = 'prison';

//Mission variables
var currentMission = 'breakOut';

//Store
$("#media-icon1").click(function() {
    if (Modernizr.localstorage) {
        localStorage.setItem("curmission", currentMission);
        localStorage.setItem("curroom", currentRoom);
        localStorage.setItem("scrpmtl", scrapMetal);
        localStorage.setItem("beenprison", beenToPrison);
        addText( $('<p>Game saved.<br><br></p>'))
    }
    else {
        addText( $('<p>Browser does not support saving.<br><br></p>'))
    }
    console.log(scrapMetal);
});

//Remove storage
$("#media-icon2").click(function() {
    if (Modernizr.localstorage) {
        localStorage.removeItem('curroom', 'beenprison', 'scrpmtl', 'curmission');
        addText( $('<p>Save erased.<br><br></p>'))
    }
    else {
        addText( $('<p>Browser does not support saving so there is nothing to delete.<br><br></p>'))
    }
    console.log(scrapMetal);
});

//Add a P element to the placeholder in the focus screen
var addText = function(el) {
        el.hide().appendTo('#placeholder').fadeIn(1000);
    }

//Check if browser support local storage using a library
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (Modernizr.localstorage) {
        addText( $('<p>Your browser supports local storage. Game data can be saved by pressing the save button.<br><br></p>'))
        scrapMetal = localStorage.scrpmtl;
        if (scrapMetal === null) {
            scrapMetal = false;
        }
        else {
            scrapMetal = localStorage.scrpmtl;
        }
    }
    else {
      addText( $('<p>Your browser does not support local storage. Your game can not be saved. Please use another browser or update your current browser.<br><br></p>'))
    }
    console.log(scrapMetal);
});
```

Comment: check the modernizer docs...are you sure `if (Modernizr.localstorage)` shouldn't be `if (Modernizr.localStorage)`? Note the case differences. Or just use `if(window.localStorage)`

Comment: To set keys on localstorage you have use setItem as localstorage.setitem("keyname,value) and to get it is localstorage.getItem("keyname")

Comment: @charlietfl `localstorage` is written correctly.

Comment: @Geeky you can also use `localStorage.value = value;`. Source: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add that the data should be converted to JSON before being set.

```
localStorage.setItem("scrapMetal", JSON.stringify(false));
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("scrapMetal"));
```

Otherwise you will see the string "false", and not the boolean false.